# Fast computation of squared norm and normalized vector with Eigen

Tags: c++, optimization, distance, eigen, division

I have a section of my code that needs to run millions of times. It seems that the most costly part of it is this computation:

```
Vector2d directedInverseSquare(Vector2d &pos1, Vector2d &pos2) {

    Vector2d diff = pos2 - pos1;
    Vector2d rHat = diff.normalized();
    double rSquared = diff.squaredNorm();

    return rHat / rSquared;
}
```

Which computes `1/r^2` in the direction of `pos1`->`pos2`, where `r` is the distance between them.
This is also equivalent to `R/r^3`, where R is the original difference vector. But I have found the form the code is written here to be faster.

It seems to me that the obvious way to make this code faster would be to somehow "produce" both the squared distance and the normed vector at once. Their computation process is pretty similar, and yet I still currently call them one after the other without any such optimization.

I've tried to do it myself, but Eigen always comes out faster. So perhaps an Eigen function that does this would be best, but I've not found a function like that.

Comment: I do not know Eigen library, but I have implemented 2D vector class which is quite similar. To me, there are *2* divisions in the code snippet, as `normalized()` require one. I would try to have only *1* division with something like `return diff / (diff.norm() * rSquared);`

Comment: Wow, that instantly improved the performance by 10%! I knew division was bad, but not this bad. Thank you for this!

Comment: You may get another minor improvement by `diff / (rSquared * std::sqrt(rSquared))` or `1.0 / (rSquared * std::sqrt(rSquared)) * diff` -- but possibly the compiler already optimizes that for you. Other than that, if you have a lot of independent computations of that form, you can have the sqrt-ing and division better vectorized (but that would likely require changing the way you store your data).

Comment: Do you do this for a whole array of data? Doing this operation "in bulk" would be potentially much faster but for that you have to show us some surrounding code.

Comment: Also, when you compared to `R/r^3`, did you do a simple `R / (r * r * r)` or did you invoke the potentially costly `pow(r, 3)`?

Comment: As pointed out in previous comments, doing scalar operations is not efficient, not only because the CPU can do multiple operation at the same time thanks to SIMD instructions, but also because of the high latency of FP instructions (causing this code to be likely latency-bound). Object-oriented codes are often (very) inefficient (partially) because of that. [Data oriented design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-oriented_design) is a common way to improve performance in such a case. It can require significant changes, but the performance impact is often pretty big too.

Comment: Once (automatically) vectorized, note that the code can be made twice faster using simple precision, and four times faster by reducing again the precision (thanks to specific x86 instructions).

Comment: @JérômeRichard My code is data oriented, as far as I know. I have an object which contains arrays of data, instead of an array of objects which contain data. This indeed made my code faster.

Comment: @Homer512 For now I do this on only 3 vectors. But I plan to run this program in parallel, and perhaps clumping up the computations of the different instances would be best. Would this "bulk" thing be achieved by vectorization?
Also, as for the `r*r*r` thing, it seems to be slower than prapin's solution by a noticable margin.

Comment: @chtz both options seem to be slower. As I said in the post, Eigen seems to always be faster, especially with the `norm`. For some reason computing the `std::sqrt` is always worse.

Comment: Re "I do this on only 3 vectors.": Do you compute it for each pair of differences between these 3 vectors? Or 1 fixed vector versus 3 different vectors?

Comment: If `std::sqrt` is worse, you could try compiling with `-fno-math-errno` (assuming gcc/clang). The math-errno is likely ignored everywhere anyways.

Comment: If you push the data oriented design to its limits, then you should not have a `Vector2d` but 2 array/vector of `n` items. The former for the `x` values and the later for the `y` values. The result can be stored in a class handling `n` items at once. This approach is significantly better for SIMD computations because of a more contiguous layout. Currently, the compiler needs to shuffle items (at best) and this is expensive. Some compilers can fail to auto-vectorize the code because of that.

Comment: Note that you need to check the assembly code to see how good is the generated code (or provide the exact command and code so we can reproduce it). Besides, note that if the arrays are huge, then you can use multiple threads.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Well, I was under the impression that `Vector2d` stores values in adjacent memory cells anyway. So the array is just `[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]` (I have only 3 objects), and the CPU cache can still get all the data in one go. Also, I usually use `x` and `y` at the same time, since they are just different coordinates of the same object. Would I still get an improvement despite this?

Comment: @chtz Sorry for not specifying that. I compute differences between 3 vectors: `a-b`, `b-c`, `c-a`, where `a,b,c` are all vectors.

Comment: The `Vector2d` can be stored contiguously (and is typically if you store them in an array), but the internal layout is sub-optimal for SIMD operations. With the `(x1,y1),(x2,y2)` layout, the subtraction can be done efficiently in SIMD (packed load + packed subtract), but then the normalization is less efficient due to horizontal operations (and a possible check of zero length vector btw). This means some SIMD lane may not be active (certainly half) assuming the target compiler do vectorize it. If the function is not inlined (unlikely), the code cannot be vectorized.

Comment: A good compiler can do shuffle and operate on 2 inlined calls of `directedInverseSquare` but this is a non-trivial optimization (so it is fragile and certainly not done by all compilers). Thus, it is not about having a cache-friendly algorithm but a SIMD-friendly one. This problem is known as the ["AoS vs SoA"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) layout. The later is often more efficient due to being more SIMD-friendly. However, it can be less cache-friendly for huge arrays and many components. In this case, the best structure is AoSoA (which is quite cumbersome to implement though).

Comment: Here, I think AoS should be enough for this use-case. It depends what you do with the vectors before and after that. Algorithms and data structures are closely interrelated. Speeding up this part of the code can slow down others. I can't be sure you will get a faster code without the assembly code nor a *minimal reproducible example* (as stated before), but I expect a theoretical speed-up up to x2 due to the previous comment explanation (guess).

Comment: In my tests, both the straightforward `diff / (r*r*r)` and @chtz's `diff / (rSquared * std::sqrt(rSquared))` is faster by a considerable margin. And it also makes sense since the assembly is just better. I don't know. Maybe it is a latency rather than throughput issue that I'm not seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with the discussion dying off, here is my test code and improved versions.

First, my benchmark. Nothing fancy.

```cpp
struct AoS
{
    Eigen::Vector2d a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    const int repetitions = 2000000;
    constexpr int blocks = 340; // ~ 16 kiB
    AoS inbufs[blocks], outbufs[blocks];
    for(AoS& buf: inbufs)
        for(Eigen::Vector2d* vec: {&buf.a, &buf.b, &buf.c})
            *vec = Eigen::Vector2d::Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < blocks; ++j) {
            const AoS& in = inbufs[j];
            AoS& out = outbufs[j];
            out.a = directedInverseSquare(in.a, in.b);
            out.b = directedInverseSquare(in.b, in.c);
            out.c = directedInverseSquare(in.c, in.a);
        }
        // don't optimize the store away
        asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
    }
}
```

Compile flags `-DNDEBUG -march=native -fno-math-errno` compiled with gcc-12.3. On my TigerLake CPU, this takes 6.2 seconds with your implementation.

Switching to the straightforward `diff / r**3` gives us 4.5 seconds:

```cpp
Eigen::Vector2d directedInverseSquare2(
        const Eigen::Vector2d &pos1, const Eigen::Vector2d &pos2)
{
    Eigen::Vector2d diff = pos2 - pos1;
    double r = diff.norm();
    return diff / (r * r * r);
}
```

chtz's version is about the same speed but fewer instructions. Objectively I think this is the best.

```cpp
Eigen::Vector2d directedInverseSquare3(
        const Eigen::Vector2d &pos1, const Eigen::Vector2d &pos2)
{
    Eigen::Vector2d diff = pos2 - pos1;
    double rSquared = diff.squaredNorm();
    return diff / (rSquared * std::sqrt(rSquared));
}
```

To improve upon this, we should vectorize by using a 2x3 matrix. This allows us to do the `b-a` and `c-b` case in one step. The `a-c` operation has to be done separately.

```cpp
using Matrix23d = Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 3>;

void directedInverseSquare(Matrix23d& out, const Matrix23d& in)
{
    Eigen::Array22d diffs = in.rightCols<2>() - in.leftCols<2>();
    Eigen::Array2d rSquared = diffs.colwise().squaredNorm();
    out.leftCols<2>() = diffs.rowwise() / (rSquared * rSquared.sqrt()).transpose();
    Eigen::Vector2d diff3 = in.col(0) - in.col(2);
    double rSquared3 = diff3.squaredNorm();
    out.col(2) = diff3 / (rSquared3 * std::sqrt(rSquared3));
}
int main()
{
    const int repetitions = 2000000;
    constexpr int blocks = 340; // ~ 16 kiB
    Matrix23d inbufs[blocks], outbufs[blocks];
    for(Matrix23d& buf: inbufs)
        buf = Matrix23d::Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < blocks; ++j)
            directedInverseSquare(outbufs[j], inbufs[j]);
        asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is only slightly faster in my tests; 4.3 seconds. The assembly looks fine, though.- I also tested a transposed version which is slightly worse.

However, this matrix style, especially the transposed version, works very well if you have many more vectors. The benefit of vectorization increases, the relative cost of that last scalar element decreases.

```cpp
void directedInverseSquare(Eigen::MatrixX2d& out, const Eigen::MatrixX2d& in)
{
    const Eigen::Index n = in.rows();
    const auto& diffs = in.bottomRows(n - 1) - in.topRows(n - 1);
    const auto& rsquared = diffs.rowwise().squaredNorm().array();
    out.topRows(n - 1) = diffs.array().colwise() / (rsquared * rsquared.sqrt());
    Eigen::Vector2d diff3 = in.row(0) - in.row(n - 1);
    double rSquared3 = diff3.squaredNorm();
    // note the eval() to force vectorized evaluation
    out.row(n - 1) = (diff3 / (rSquared3 * std::sqrt(rSquared3))).eval();
}
int main()
{
    const int repetitions = 2000000;
    constexpr int blocks = 340; // ~ 16 kiB
    Eigen::MatrixX2d inbufs, outbufs(340 * 3, 2);
    inbufs = Eigen::MatrixX2d::Random(340 * 3, 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
        directedInverseSquare(outbufs, inbufs);
        asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");
    }
}
```

This takes 2.8 seconds. As usual, be careful with those [`auto` variables in Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html).

As a bonus, here is the best version I could come up with for the 2x3 matrix version using [Intel intrinsics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html) with AVX + FMA instructions. This takes 4.1 seconds.

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

void directedInverseSquare(Matrix23d& out, const Matrix23d& in)
{
    const double* inptr = in.data();
    // [b0, b1, c0, c1]
    __m256d rightcols = _mm256_loadu_pd(inptr + 2);
    // [a0, a1, b0, b1]
    __m256d leftcols = _mm256_loadu_pd(inptr);
    // [b0 - a0, b1 - a1, c0 - b0, c1 - b1]
    __m256d diffs = _mm256_sub_pd(rightcols, leftcols);
    // [c0, c1]
    __m128d cvec = _mm256_extractf128_pd(rightcols, 1);
    // [a0, a1]
    __m128d avec = _mm256_castpd256_pd128(leftcols);
    // [a0 - c0, a1 - c1]
    __m128d taildiff = _mm_sub_pd(avec, cvec);
    __m256d taildiff256 = _mm256_castpd128_pd256(taildiff);
    // [b0 - a0, a0 - c0, c0 - b0, x]
    __m256d lowvals = _mm256_unpacklo_pd(diffs, taildiff256);
    // [b1 - a1, a1 - c1, c1 - b1, x]
    __m256d highvals = _mm256_unpackhi_pd(diffs, taildiff256);
    // [norm(b-a)**2, norm(a-c)**2, norm(c-b)**2, x]
    __m256d rsquared = _mm256_mul_pd(lowvals, lowvals);
    rsquared = _mm256_fmadd_pd(highvals, highvals, rsquared);
    // [norm(b-a), norm(a-c), norm(c-b), x]
    __m256d r = _mm256_sqrt_pd(rsquared);
    // [norm(b-a)**3, norm(a-c)**3, norm(c-b)**3, x]
    __m256d rcubed = _mm256_mul_pd(r, rsquared);
    // [norm(b-a)**3, norm(b-a)**3, norm(c-b)**3, norm(c-b)**3]
    __m256d bcast1 = _mm256_permute_pd(rcubed, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0));
    // [norm(b-a)**3, norm(a-c)**3]
    __m128d rcubed128 = _mm256_castpd256_pd128(rcubed);
    // [norm(a-c)**3, norm(a-c)**3]
    __m128d bcast2 = _mm_permute_pd(rcubed128, _MM_SHUFFLE2(1, 1));
    // [(b0-a0)/norm(b-a)**3, ..., (c1-b1)/norm(c-b)**3]
    __m256d result1 = _mm256_div_pd(diffs, bcast1);
    // [(a0-c0)/norm(a-c)**3, (a1-c1)/norm(a-c)**3]
    __m128d result2 = _mm_div_pd(taildiff, bcast2);
    double* outptr = out.data();
    _mm256_storeu_pd(outptr, result1);
    _mm_store_pd(outptr + 4, result2);
}
```

(note that `unpacklo` and `unpackhi` have rather unintuitive results for 256 bit vectors)

Comment: Interesting! However, I wonder if AVX is really useful here. Indeed, some of the instructions have a significant latency and AVX does not help for that. SSE code might be as fast or close to due to a better pipelining (latency is overlapped with computations). Besides instructions like sqrtpd/divpd are not faster with AVX on Intel CPUs so far (AFAIK this is the same thing on AMD Zen CPUs).

Comment: @JérômeRichard uops.info lists the same measured throughput for `VSQRTPD (XMM, XMM)` and `VSQRTPD (YMM, YMM)` on Zen 3, same for `VDIVPD`. But you are right, my Tiger Lake cannot improve with that. Honestly, I just picked AVX+FMA as a baseline since nothing else was specified and I assume most high-performance code developed today can use that.